# FFmpeg merging two audio filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to merge two ffmpeg filters (`dynaudnorm` and `loudnorm`) in a batch file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af dynaudnorm=g=7:m=30, -af loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1:LRA=3 -ar 44.1k out.mp3
```

but the result is that only the second filter (`loudnorm`) is executed. Is something wrong with this code or is it impossible to merge two filters?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate multiple filters in a filterchain:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af dynaudnorm=g=7:m=30,loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1:LRA=3 -ar 44.1k out.mp3
```

Simply add a `,` between them (see [manual](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1)):

> A filterchain consists of a sequence of connected filters, each one connected to the previous one in the sequence. A filterchain is represented by a list of ","-separated filter descriptions.

You can also combine multiple filterchains into a filtergraph. See the [Filtering Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) for more info and some examples.

Comment: Oh, yes... Superfluous space after comma. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but also no need to add two `-af` options. If you've found this useful, please consider marking the answer as accepted using the checkmark next to it.